# discord.py, sending a message in all channels with a webhook

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, webhooks

I wanted to make a command for my private server, that creates webhooks in all guild's channels and makes them send a message, I already tried to make it like this:

```
@client.command()
async def allchannel(ctx):
  for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
    webhook = discord.utils.get(await ctx.channel.webhooks())
    if not webhook:
      webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook("Test")
      await webhook.send(content="Hello")
```

But it says: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: create_webhook() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem myself, If you want to know how I did it, I just had to put this:

```
except AttributeError:
            pass
```